# Оптимальный размер фонового изображения для лендинга

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Есть Лендинг, какого размера должно быть фоновое изображение, чтобы красиво смотрелось на всех экранах устройств, чтобы сильно не увеличивалось и не расплывалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас не требуеться поддерживать IE я бы рекомедовал использовать тег [picture](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture). С помощью него можно будет задать несколько размеров отдного и того-же изображения. После чего этот тег с помощю css сделать ввиде фона.
После того как подготовите графику по размерам рекомендую воспользоваться 
сервисом [TinyPng](https://tinypng.com/).
Ключевые размеры экранов я бы брал (1920, 1280, 1024, 768 и 576px).

Answer (score 1):

1) Советую сделать на весь экран с соотношением 16:9.